# Get distinct rows combined from multiple fields (including a joined one)

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I've got two tables:

**Products**

```
ID   productname    organization 
---  ------------   ------------ 
1         X            orga #1
2         X            orga #2
```

**Artifacts**

```
ID   productID        status     revision  platform 
---  ------------   ----------   --------  --------
1         1          milestone    0.9.0      win
2         1          milestone    0.9.0      osx
3         2           release     1.0.0      win
```

What I need to combine are artifacts containing the same productId,status,revision. Their only difference is the platform which isn't part of the resultset.

The resultset should contain:
artifact-id, status, revision, productname and organization

Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: Could you please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: How do you imagine these results looking, you can't exactly return the artifact ID if you're not grouping on it(you'll either get a random one, or all of them, in which case this is no different than not grouping at all).

Comment: @scragar A random one is good enough.

Comment: Why then do you want `ID` from Artifacts if you don't care which one? That doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id artifactID, status, revision, productname, organization
FROM Products p
JOIN Artifacts a ON a.productID = p.id
GROUP BY productID, status, revision
```

Comment: that doesn't work. I just executed it and there are still duplicate (only different platform) entries.

Comment: Fixed it to use `GROUP BY` to select the columns you want distinct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all artifacts which productID same as Product id then use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.status,
       A.revision,
       P.productname,
       P.organization
FROM Artifacts A
INNER JOIN Products P ON A.productID=P.id;
```